# Internet Explorer showing list vertically when it should be displayed horizontally

Tags: css, internet-explorer, list

I've got a list of 3 buttons that need to display horizontally. All's good in FF but IE is stacking them directly on top of one another. My code for the list items is bellow.

Thanks for your help

```
<style type="text/css"> 


          #navigation { 
       list-style: none;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 278px;
        padding: 0;
        text-align:left;
        z-index:1;    

    }

    #navigation li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #navigation a {
        display: block;
        width: 140px;
        height: 15px;
        background: url("http://aracelid.110mb.com/boton_ROLLOUT_08.png") no-repeat;
        padding: 10px 0.5em;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size:12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #navigation a:hover {
        background: url("http://aracelid.110mb.com/boton_ROLLOVER_08.png") no-repeat;
    }


           #one, #two,#three {background: url("http://aracelid.110mb.com/boton_ROLLOUT_08.png") no-repeat 0px 0px;}

         #one_div{width:140px;height:36px;}
#two_div{width:140px;height:36px;}
#three_div{width:140px;height:36px;}
```

```
<ul id="navigation"> 
    <li><a href="#" id="one" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;" ><div id="one_div">One</div></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" id="two" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;"><div id="two_div" >Two</div></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#" id="three" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;"><div id="three_div" >Three</div></a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a float:left in navgivation li class..

```
 #navigation li {
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: display values are ignored when float is used. Unless it's IE6 then display:inline can be used to fix a double margin bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
}
```